# How to pass list1 to listview as shown below

Tags: android, android-activity

```
package com.example.simplemath;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle; import
android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.ListView;
public class Review extends Activity  {
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.review);
    ArrayList<Question> list1 = (ArrayList<Question>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myList");
    ListView review=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list1);         
    review.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
 } 
}
```

Comment: Since your list is not just a List<String>, you will need a custom adapter and a custom list item.

Comment: can you show procedure please...@PhilippJahoda